# Dart/Flutter - How to avoid auto rounding done by NumberFormat.compactCurrency(locale: "en_IN").format() method while formatting a value?

Tags: flutter, dart

Dart/Flutter - How to avoid auto rounding done by NumberFormat.compactCurrency(locale: "en_IN").format() method while formatting a value?

```
num value = 29886964;
NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.compactCurrency(locale: "en_IN");
String output = numberFormat.format(value);
```

Actual output = INR2.99Cr

Requirement/Expectation: INR2.98Cr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use NumberFormat.currency api

```
num value = 29886964;
NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.compactCurrency(locale: "en_IN" );
final count = math.pow(10 , (value.toString().length - numberFormat.significantDigits));
var result = value / count;
String output = numberFormat.format(result.floor() * count);
print(output);
```

value : INR2.98Cr

Comment: I required the output as exact INR2.98Cr. 
So, Can you give me a way to convert 2,98,86,964.00 to INR2.98Cr

Comment: You are my saviour bro. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The Accepted answer didn't work for me, unfortunately.
So, this is my answer.

```
    extension DoubleExtension on double {

        String get formattedCurrency {
            final formatter = NumberFormat.currency(symbol: '\$', decimalDigits: 2);
            return formatter.format(this);
        }

      // Another way around
      String get formattedCurrency_2 {
        final formatter = NumberFormat('###.0#');
        return formatter.format(this);
      }
    }
```

and you can use the extension this way:

```
<your_double_number>.formattedCurrency;
```

Don't forget to import the extension in your class.

For more info about the configuration please look at this document:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/NumberFormat-class.html

Comment: Thanks for sharing 